# Converge in norm and converge point wise are not equivalent.

Tags: normed-spaces, pointwise-convergence

I have known that for sequences of functions in $C[0,1]$, converge point wise is not equivalent with converge in norm for that two special norms:
Integral and Suprem.
However, when it comes to any norm in that space, I don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: This is a difficult question. The following article contains a proof of the fact that topology of pointwise convergence is not even metrizable.

http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1951-002-01/S0002-9939-1951-0040647-7/S0002-9939-1951-0040647-7.pdf

Comment: This question has been discussed several times on MSE. I got above reference from another question on MSE.